# Not able to highlight the file in JTree

Tags: java, jtree

I have created a JTree in which I want to highlight a file and if the directory containing the file is invisible, I need to expand it.

Ex:
I have created a JTree with the root node- D:/Company/abb/src.
The file which I want to highlight is - D:/Company/abb/src/bin/help.txt

Please give me some logic to highlight the file help.txt.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have a JTree which represents the file system.  Here's my code to cause a specific directory to be selected (and the tree expanded and the view scrolled if required).

```
JTree fsTree;

void setSelectedPath(String pth) {
    TreePath                        jtp=buildTreePath(new File(pth));

    fsTree.setSelectionPath(jtp);
    if(fsTree.getSelectionPath()==null) { fsTree.setSelectionRow(0);       }
    else                                { fsTree.scrollPathToVisible(jtp); }
    }

public TreePath buildTreePath(File dir) {
    ArrayList                           elms=new ArrayList();

    do { elms.add(0,dir); } while((dir=dir.getParentFile())!=null);
    elms.add(0,root);
    return new TreePath(elms.toArray(new File[elms.size()]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[JTree](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html).[makeVisible()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#makeVisible(javax.swing.tree.TreePath)) should be what you need.

Comment: That depends on the model of your JTree. You can construct a TreePath by specifying the single components that make up the path. Check the documentation.

Comment: Can u plz give me an example to build the TreePath.
I am using DefaultTreeModel.
It helps me a lot.

Comment: AFAIK you have to create your own model for this kind of feature.